# “The location constraint is not valid” When Creating Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, magento

I've just signed up for an Azure account to test it out as a possible hosting solution, but when I try and create a VM from the VM Depot I seem to get the error "The location constraint is not valid", regardless of what location I use. I'm trying to use the Magento images, and tried several of them and several regions, but got this error every time when it failed to create the VM. Same error happens trying to create a Wordpress VM.

I'm just using the built in Azure management tools rather than anything custom, at manage.windowsazure.com, then click on Virtual Machines -> Images -> Browse VM Depot, selecting a Magento/Wordpress image and filling out the form. Creating an image from the standard VMs seems to work, but the storage containers for those aren't available when using a pre-built image.

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so does anyone know how it can be sorted?

Thanks